# How can I include pay-later contributions in a widget thermometer?

Tags: contribution-page, paylater

I have a contribution page which is collecting live donations and pay-later contributions.

I'm using the contribution page widget to display a thermometer with the total raised by this contribution page.

The thermometer includes donations, but not pay-later contributions.

What can I do to include pay-later contributions in the thermometer, too?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually easy, but totally hidden...

1. At the very end of the code for your widget, find the last `<script>` tag, which looks something like this:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
   ```

   where  is a very long URL.
2. Modify this URL by adding `&includePending=1` to the end.
3. Paste your modified widget code over the old widget code wherever you are using the widget.
4. Observe that pending contributions now affect the thermometer total, even contributions which have already been made.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably included in a later upgrade that I haven't done yet, but I had to add the following to `/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/widget.php` to get this @sean-colsen's answer to work:

```
$includePending = isset( $_GET['includePending'] ) ? true : false;
$data = CRM_Contribute_BAO_Widget::getContributionPageData($cpageId, $widgetId, $includePending);
```